# Importing data from Access to Excel via VBA. Trouble with way values are being imported

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to import all data from 3 columns in an access database (.mdb) into my Excel file, which is working, however the numbers that I'm importing aren't coming in correct. You can see in the images supplied what exactly is happening. I am wanting it to import exactly as it is in the database (to 1 decimal place). Now I've tried with changing the numberformat for the Excel columns but of course that only hides the true value with a shortened version so I'd like to avoid doing that.

Dealing with SQL in VBA is something new to me and I don't know Access very well either so I'm wondering if there is something I can add to the query that could affect why the numbers are changing when they get copied into my Excel sheet.

I'm going to be adding a lot more to the code later but just testing connection for now to get it working properly first.
Here is my code (Got the basis for it from a youtube video I found):

```
    Sub GetDataFromAccess()

Application.screenupdating = False

On Error GoTo SubError

Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset, xlSheet As Worksheet, recCount As Long, SQL As String, _
TableName As String, FldrLoc As String, FileName As String, ImpSh As Worksheet

Set ImpSh = Sheets("Import")
FldrLoc = ImpSh.Range("D10").Value
FileName = ImpSh.Range("Q15").Value

If Right(FldrLoc, 1) = "\" Then
    DbLoc = FldrLoc & FileName
Else
    DbLoc = FldrLoc & "\" & FileName
End If

Set xlSheet = Sheets("CAL-53 INC")
If InStr(ImpSh.Range("Q15").Value, ".mdb") > 0 Then
    TableName = ImpSh.Range("R5").Value & Left(ImpSh.Range("Q15").Value, Len(ImpSh.Range("Q15")) - 4)
Else
    TableName = ImpSh.Range("R5").Value & ImpSh.Range("Q15").Value
End If

xlSheet.Range("G3:I5000").ClearContents

Application.StatusBar = "Connecting to the database..."
Application.Cursor = xlWait

Set db = OpenDatabase(DbLoc)

SQL = "SELECT LRP_CHAINAGE, LEFT_DEPTH, RIGHT_DEPTH" & _
    " FROM " & TableName & " ORDER BY LRP_CHAINAGE "

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

Application.StatusBar = "Writing to spreadsheet..."
If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No data from that table"
    GoTo SubExit
Else
    rs.MoveLast
    recCount = rs.RecordCount
    rs.MoveFirst
End If

xlSheet.Range("G3").CopyFromRecordset rs
'xlSheet.Range("G:I").NumberFormat = "0.0"

Application.StatusBar = "Update complete."


SubExit:
On Error Resume Next
    Application.Cursor = xlDefault
    rs.Close
    
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
    
    Application.screenupdating = True
    
    Exit Sub
    
SubError:

    Application.StatusBar = ""
    MsgBox "Error: " & vbCrLf & Err.Number & " = " & Err.Description
    Resume SubExit

End Sub
```

Here are the pictures of what is in the database and what it's coming in as:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Access and Excel got the same *feature* What you see **is not** always what you get. Are you sure the values stored in your Access database are **stored** with only 1 decimal? Have you checked? What are the properties of the fields?

Comment: The data type is "Number" and the Field Size is "Single". I can't go manually changing these if need be as there are dozens of mdb files that I will end up looping through so I need something in the process to change. If I were to copy and paste the column from Access manually it will give the values shown in the database. I know there is some For loop which potentially fixes the problem but not sure how I could integrate that to this even if it does. I've seen another question regarding this same issue but none of the answers helped my understanding of it.

Comment: A totally different approach could be to use Power Query for this

Comment: What about `SELECT Format([LRP_CHAINAGE],"0.0")*1 AS Expr1, Format([LEFT_DEPTH],"0.0")*1 AS Expr2, Format([RIGHT_DEPTH],"0.0")*1 AS Expr3
FROM Table1;
`

Comment: I don't know how I'm supposed to get that to work Foxfire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick work around you may set the SQL statement as follows:

```
SQL = "SELECT  Fix(10*[" & TableName & "]![LRP_CHAINAGE])/10 AS LRP_CHAINAGE, Fix(10*[" & TableName & "]![LEFT_DEPTH])/10 AS LEFT_DEPTH, Fix(10*[" & TableName & "]![RIGHT_DEPTH])/10 AS RIGHT_DEPTH" & _
" FROM " & TableName & " ORDER BY LRP_CHAINAGE "
```

This will give you only one digit after decimal. If you need two digits just change multiplier and divider to 100 :)

Comment: This could be good enough for me but it's giving the following error: `3075 = Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Fix(10*[LCMS_Rut_Processed_BOP2_Dec_50_1]![LEFT_DEPTH] AS LEFT_DEPTH, SELECT  Fix(10*[LCMS_Rut_Processed_BOP2_Dec_50_1]![RIGHT_DEPTH] AS RIGHT_DEPTH FROM LCMS_Rut_Processed_BOP2_Dec_50_1 ORDER BY LRP_CHAINAGE'.`
My eyes can't see what's wrong with it.

Comment: missing closing partentheses

Comment: I'm not sure if using fix function is relevant as it will round the data. Since in the data, there is always one number after the decimal (decimal fraction), tou may want to multiply by 10 every column in the select query and then in excel using copy 10 in the clipboard and paste special divide values or using vba quick macro record for the specified columns

Comment: I modified the code. Sorry for typo error on last two fields there was missing parentheses and divider as well. you can try now.
Regarding the the fix function if you check the usage you will notice that I fix the value after mutiplying by 10 so I get the first digit saved then I divide the result by 10 again.
Execution example for number 23.45
- Multiply by 10 => 23.45 * 10 = 234.5
- Fix the result => 234
- Divide by 10 => 234/10 = 23.4
I hope it is clear now

Comment: You don't need to make any calculations to the resulting Excel sheet as you will get it directly

Comment: Needed to remove the second SELECT that was in the code cause it gave another syntax error but after that it works great. Thanks.

Comment: Great and sorry for typing errors. I amended the code after your finding to be working for next solution seeker.

Comment: Hey I've just discovered an issue. Using this if it was "5.199999809" then when it imports it comes in as 5.1 instead of 5.2. Would using Round work better instead of Fix? I tried and seems to work replacing Fix with Round and leaving all else the same, but not sure if that's right.

Comment: Also if you don't mind, I tried with removing the "AS" bits from the code which still works fine so I don't get what the purpose of it is?

Comment: I used Round before posting solution and it didn't give me good results (may be I used wrong argument value) but I tried it now again and it seems to be working fine. Of course it would be better to use it and set precision argument to 1 (don't use the 10 as multiplier and divider as you don't need it in Round).

Regarding AS normally calculated fields should have names and AS is used to give them the desired name. Otherwise Access will give generic names as Expr1, Expr2, ... . If it works for you then it is OK.

Comment: There is no (The only solution). Usually you find here basic solution that puts you on track then you can customize to fulfill your needs and of course you can ask again for help if you still face troubles and we all learn from each other.

Comment: Hmm I tried without the 10* and /10 but it seems to still give the long numbers which I don't get. Did `Round([" & TableName & "]![" & Column1 & "],1) AS " & Column1 & ",` (Column1 replaced LRP_CHAINAGE) but doesn't round to 1 decimal place. Obviously that's just for 1 of the 3 columns. If I switch the 1 to a 0 for the rounding it works but not if I set to 1. And regardless of what I set the round to if I utilize the 10* and /10 it seems to work. I will look more into it but if you had any further insight it would be great.

Comment: This is the same problem I faced with Round so I didn't use it. Instead you can still use Fix and round the numbers yourself. This would be as follows (for one column and you can replicate for other two:

    `"Fix(10*([" & TableName & "]![" & Column1 & "] + 0.05)) / 10 AS " & Column1 & "`

Just add 0.05 to the number before multiplication by 10 inside Fix and you get your number rounded.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL = "SELECT LRP_CHAINAGE*10, LEFT_DEPTH*10, RIGHT_DEPTH*10" & _
    " FROM " & TableName & " ORDER BY LRP_CHAINAGE "
```

I'm not running access or windows, but I remember I've done something like this with sql server and excel since vba truncate decimal values

After this query, you can use an update query on the worksheet

```
UPDATE [IMPORT$]
SET LRP_CHAINAGE=LRP_CHAINAGE/10, LEFT_DEPTH/10, RIGHT_DEPTH/10
```

Comment: This will keep the same problem as it will keep sending the full Single number to Excel as you still didn't cut the extra digits. So even after dividing you will get the extra digits.

Comment: We don't know if you want to keep the precision of your numbers because access seems to store these number with a specific format, you can see that in the field properties. In excel, the field property in access doesn't apply so you get a full precision number. You can reapply a format in the sql query as said in a comment earlier from Foxfire And Burns And Burns, or within excel the format dialog box and it will show one decimal if you choose something like #,#. Now if you want to change the data so it looks like the same as what's displayed in access, you may have to use string formula

Comment: and a few conditions like when you have integers, you don't want a decimal to show up. That could be done in vba and also in sql, it depends on what you're most comfortable with

Comment: can you show the design view of the access data type field for the single values so we can see how this data is stored